# ¿Cómo capturar evento click de la flecha del action bar en un Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Quiero capturar el evento click de la flecha del action bar que aparece con el metodo `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` Si es posible dadme respuesta tanto en un `Activity` como en un `Fragmente` que es lo que estoy usando, dejo codigo de un proyecto de ejemplo y gracias de antemano.

Aqui mi `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initComponents();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0: tab.setText("first"); break;
                    case 1: tab.setText("second"); break;
                }
            }
        });
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager_2);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    }
}
```

La idea seria desde el siguiente `Fragment` controlar la flecha para que cambie por ejemplo el `TextView`

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    
    private View view;
    private TextView textView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        initComponents();
        
        return view;
    }
    
    //Aqui deberia de estar el metodo de la flecha para cambiar el editText
    
    private void initComponents(){
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución correcta para el evento **click** de la flecha en un **Fragment** consta de 2 pasos.

1. Sobreescribir el **metodo** `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
         //Lógica
         return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

2. Incluir en el `onCreateView` el **metodo** `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` este ultimo lo que hace es informar que este **Fragment** quiere participar en el rellenado del **optionMenu**, sin esto el **Fragment** no respondera al **metodo** del paso 1.

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        initComponents();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa el metodo siguiente ,el metodo funciona tanto para la Activity como el Fragment ,Espero que te pueda ayudar. [MARCALA COMO RESPONDIDA SI TE FUNCIONA]

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {

     //AQUI IRA EL CODIGO QUE QUIERAS IMPLEMENTAR AL USAR EL BOTON

         return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     
  }
```

Comment: Este codigo solo funciona en el Activity, necesito una opcion para el fragmento.